# primefaces p:calendar year rage set range only by entered range

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I would like to set range of the calendar in range from 1916-2026 if current year is 2016. I am using this:

yearRange="c-100:c+10"

First when the calendar is loaded it is set ok, but for example if I choose year 2000 i get values from 1900 to 2010. How can I resolve this to set years only between 1916-2026.

Thanks,

Comment: max date helps me

Comment: min date does not exists

Comment: version 6.0 says in pom file